# FFmpeg: how to make video out of slides and audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

So i have several images some png and some jpgs. And i have mp3 audio. I want to make a video file don't care what format.

So i want either:

A video made up of xyz size meaning images are centered and cropped if they go beyond dimensions coupled with audio in mp3 format..

or just one image centered or and cropped, still image, video with audio.

I have tried copying and pasting things and even modifying them after reading documents but in the end i got a blank video with audio and huge file that took forever to complete.

I have windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

u have to rename the images in a sequence.

example if u have a.png , bds.png , asda.png....

rename it to image1.png, image2.png , image3.png and so on

(it should be in the sequence u want the images to come in the video)

now make sure u are in the folder u have saved the rename images

now use
`ffmpeg -i image%d.png output.mp4` (whichever format u want)

now to add audio(say 'input.mp3') to 'output.mp4'

use `ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -i output.mp4 output2.mp4`

this should work.

hope this helps.